# Не могу понять JMS

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, jms

Мне дали задание разработать отправку сообщений в брокер и получение от туда на языке программирования java используя Java Message Servise. Дело в том что никогда не занимался разработкой под JAVA EE, максимум что делал это простой REST сервис с использованием SPRING. Подскажите, в какую сторону мне смотреть и где брать информацию по данному вопросу? И еще вопрос, необходимо ли использовать для решения данной задачи какие либо брокеры на подобие ACTIVEMQ? Брокеры запускаются через контейнер tomcat и другие или каким то другим образом?

Comment: Как вы надеетесь обойтись без использования брокера в задаче отправки сообщения в брокер?..

Comment: я не надеюсь обойтись без использования брокера, меня интересует есть ли хороший туториал, в котором можно посмотреть реализацию, книга или еще какой нибудь источник

Comment: Java EE имеет так называемый Web profile и Full platform. Web profile не обязывает сервер поддерживать JMS, и tomcat, реализуя только Web profile, его и не поддерживает. Без внешнего брокера не обойтись. Но Вы можете воспользоваться сервером Full platform, которые имеют встроенный брокер, Например Wildfly 10 использует встроенный ActiveMQ. На самом деле всё зависит от задания. Если есть свобода выбора, то лучше делать для Full platform. Меньше разбираться, если приёмник и передатчик сообщений должны работать в одном сервере.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДементьев я думаю, что вы попали :) JMS одна из самых сложных и в то же время востребованных частей в J2EE (в отличие от enterprise bean'ов) - так что удачи.